# Inspire from Kantorovich Inequality

Tags: inequalities

Inspire from [Kantorovich Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KantorovichInequality.html) and [my previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/245092/a-conjecture-generalization-of-karamata-inequality). I am looking for a proof of the nice inequality as following:

Let $f(x)$ is a real continuous function that is strictly convex on $[m, M]$, let $m \le x_i \le M$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ then show that:

$$nf\left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)+n\left(f(M)+f(m)-2f\left(\frac{M+m}{2}\right)\right) \ge f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)$$

Equality holds if only if $m=x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=M$

Comment: Why $n$ twice on the left rather than once in the denominator on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. Choose a linear function $\ell(x)$ such that $\ell(m)=f(m),\ell(M)=f(M)$. Denoting $g=f-\ell$ we get $g(m)=g(M)=0$ and have to prove $$ng\left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)-2ng\left(\frac{M+m}{2}\right) \geqslant g(x_1)+\cdots+g(x_n).$$
But $g$ is convex, thus $g$ is non-positive on $[m,M$]. So, RHS is non-positive, and it suffices to prove that LHS is non-negative.  Indeed, if we denote $t=\frac{x_1+\dots+x_n}n$, $s=\frac{m+M}2$, then $g(t)\geqslant g(t)+g(2s-t)\geqslant 2g(s)$.

Comment: Dear Dr Fedor Petrov, Thank to You very much for your proof. I think the inequality is true with weighted version. And I think it is a generalization of Kantorovic inequality. What do you think with my remarks? Thank to You again.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ is a real continuous function that is strictly convex on $[m, M]$, let $m \le x_i \le M$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, $\lambda_i > 0$ and $\sum_1^{n} \lambda_i = 1$  then show that:

$$f\left(\lambda_1x_1+\cdots+\lambda_nx_n \right)+\left(f(M)+f(m)-2f\left(\frac{M+m}{2}\right)\right) \ge \lambda_1f(x_1)+\cdots+\lambda_nf(x_n)$$

Equality holds if only if $m=x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=M$

Comment: Yes, the proof is the same.

Comment: Dear Dr @FedorPetrov , The inequality above is a generalization of the Kantorovich inequality?

Comment: I do not think so. It would be if you replace coefficient of $f(M)+f(m)-2f((m+M)/2)$ from $n$ to $n/2$. But such inequality is not true in general.

Comment: Dear Dr. @FedorPetrov If we let $x_1 \ge x_2 \ge ...\ge x_n$ 
and replaced:

$$n(f(M)+f(m)-f(\frac{M+m}{2}))=2f(x_1)+2f(x_2)+....+2f(x_n)-2(f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})-.....-2f(\frac{x_{n-1}+x_n}{2})$$ we have:

$$nf(\frac{x_1+.....+x_n}{n})+f(x_1)+....+f(x_n) \ge 2f(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})+2f(\frac{x_2+x_3}{2})+....+2f(\frac{x_{n-1}+x_n}{2})+2f(\frac{x_n+x_1}{2})$$ (1),  I conjecture that (1) is holds